# realloc: invalid next size, detected by glibc

Tags: c, size, realloc, dynamic-arrays

My code:

```
int args_size = 5;
char** args;

args = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * args_size);

// ...

args = (char**) realloc(args, sizeof(char*) * (args_size += 5));
```

I want to increase the size by 5.

But I get this error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000a971c0 ***
```

I know that a temp variable catching realloc is good, but just for simplicity...

Comment: What is `macro->args` ?

Comment: @cnicutar arrrr aorry I corrected it.

Comment: don't cast the return of `malloc`. programming throught side effects with `+=`, argh.

Comment: The problem is likely somewhere between the `malloc` and the `realloc`.

Comment: @sam You're probably overrunning the buffer somewhere along the way and corrupting the heap.  You should try running your application under `valgrind`.

Comment: Sorry once again I had to correct it... `arg` is `char** arg`

Comment: The address that glibc detected curiously looks as if the high word of your address has been clashed. This is a typical "side effect" of casting the return of `malloc` on machines with 32 bit `int` and 64 bit pointers, when you try to quiecen your compiler after forgetting to include the prototype of `malloc`.

Comment: @cnicutar Can you please tell what problem can it be?

Comment: @SAM Listen to Jens and jszakmeister. Start by including `stdlib.h` if you don't already have it.

Comment: @JensGustedt When you forget to include `stdlib.h` it's quite the same as forgetting `stdio.h` for `printf()`

Comment: I have included `stdlib.h` ... @JensGustedt I also tried removing the casting but no luck :(

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes I have 64-bit pointer and 32-bit `int`...

Comment: At any point in the code you conveniently left out, is `args` ever modified (not `*args`; **`args`**)? For example, `args++`

Comment: @WhozCraig No I didn't modify `args`... Should I post the original function?

Comment: Well, here's a big clue. The above code **verbatim**, with proper inclusion of `<stdlib.h>`, compiles and runs correctly without error in stand-alone `main()`. If there is any *better* indication that the code you're leaving out with your `// ...` marker is the root of all-things-evil, you'll be hard pressed to find it. **Yes**. Post the original function in an update to your question (not here in a comment).

Comment: My suggestion would be to step through the function in a debugger from the time the original `malloc()` is saved to `args` until you see the value stored in `args` change. That instruction is the one poking you in the eye. If you know how to use gdb to set a break-on-write data breakpoint, so much the better, but if not, just keep it simple and step through the code. And heed what everyone else here said. 1. `#include <stdlib.h>`, 2. Don't cast your malloc/realloc calls in C., 3. Use at least `-Wall -Werror` and *pay attention to warnings from your compiler.*

Comment: @WhozCraig Your instructions were very helpful! Solved the problem as I have mentioned in my answer. Please make your comments the answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Initially, the size of `args` is 5 elements.
As the program was filling `args`, it was mistakenly adding *6th* element to it and then calling `realloc`.

That caused the error mentioned in the question.

Problem is solved by eliminating the error, by following the comments of WhozCraig, Jens Gustedt and others...

Thanks to all!